# Ad something between every third post

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation where i want to ad some ads between every third post that i have made, how can i do this?

i found the following code bellow but where in the theme / code do i place it ?

```
<?php $counter =0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><!-- begin of loop -->
<?php
  ++$counter;
  if($counter == 3) {
    $postclass = 'class="third-post"';
    $counter = 0;
  } else { $postclass = ''; }
?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php echo $postclass; ?>>
<?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?><!-- end of loop -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to add an ad after every 3 posts, you need to add the above code in theme file name single.php after the below code add your code.`

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content/content', 'single' ); ?>
        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        ?>`
```